# Is there a way to force authenticated apps to prompt for the password after every screen lock?

Tags: settings, security, password

I have a password manager set-up and it's really easy to login using it.  I would prefer if certain (or all) authenticated apps required re-entering of credentials after the device has been locked.  Is there a way to accomplish this (or some similar feature/behavior that can be enabled)?